# Injecting dependencies in <head> vs package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have bootstrap dependency inside the "head" tag of html file which references physically added library files that i downloaded.

I also have a bootstrap dependency inside package.json added via npm.

I only need the dependencies in one place right? For example i can remove from "head" tag and keep inside package.json?

Comment: have you imported it in your js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dependencies inside your `package.json` does not means that dependencies are automatically used by your bundle: you have to import stuff inside your `JS/SASS` to make this happen.

You didn't said what is you bootstrap dependency, but let say is the default Bootstrap package. You have to do:

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

To have the Bootstrap CSS bundled in your application.
The same for the JavaScript source... but I don't think you really want to have Bootstrap JS in a React app. Look at [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) instead.

Comment: Okay Keul i will uninstall bootstrap and go with react bootstrap solution, thanks

Comment: @CiaranWhyte Please, read the `react-bootstrap` documentation I linked: you still need to have also `bootstrap` as `react-boostrap` is not providing any styles

Comment: Thats great thanks for the heads up, i haven't reached styling phase just yet, still adding components and functionality but as soon as ready ill refer to documentation you linked.